# Adding a function to an object (shape/MC)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am slowly becoming more experienced to AS3 from AS2 in Flash.

Is there any way you can add a function to a created object of some sort which could be a Shape or a MovieClip?

In the past, I have used:

```
var testshape = _root.createEmptyMovieClip();
testshape.onEnterFrame = function():Void
{
    testshape._alpha -= 10;
    if(testshape._alpha < 20)
    {
        testshape.removeMovieClip();
    }
}
```

Is there something similar to this I could do in AS3?

Possibly with eventListeners or something of the sort.

Currently I have it as:

```
var testshape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
testshape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); 
testshape.graphics.drawCircle(300,300,50);
testshape.graphics.endFill();
testshape.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function runEvent():void
{
    testshape.alpha -= 0.1;
    if(testshape.alpha < 0.2)
    {           
        testshape.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,runEvent);
        removeChild(testshape);
    }
});
addChild(testshape);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see a following code.

```
var testShape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(testShape);
testShape.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function():void{
    testShape.alpha -= 0.1;
    if(testShape.alpha < 0.2)
    {
        removeChild(testShape);
    }
});
```

### Edited

trying this:

```
var testShape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
testShape.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
testShape.graphics.drawCircle(100,100,100);
testShape.graphics.endFill();
addChild(testShape);
testShape.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
    testShape.alpha -= 0.1;
    if(testShape.alpha < 0.2)
    {
        testShape.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
        removeChild(testShape);
    }
};
```

Comment: I modified the code slightly so it would work with `.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,theFunctionName);`


The only other issue I have is displaying the actual MovieClip since `addChild()` doesnt seem to display it.

I have this code before adding the child:

    `testshape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    testshape.graphics.drawCircle(300,300,50);`

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now. But one quick question: does it matter if I have `addChild(testShape);` after declaring the function or before declaring the eventListener? Also, is `endFill();` necessary or does it make it make it infinitesimally faster or slower or neither?

Comment: If you're just doing simple things like alpha - take a look at green sock.com and TweenLite

Comment: I just had a question about whether the ordering of the code mattered and if `endFill();` was beneficial... and it is more complex than alpha, alpha was just as an example.